# SQL - Creating a column to use in a case but don't want to group by it

Tags: sql, group-by, teradata, transpose, calculated-columns

I'm a beginner to SQL. I'm using it in Teradata.

I want to break up food and beverage data by meal times. 
Essentially, first I'm categorizing the restaurants by a style they are. Then I'm using that style and an order time to categorize counts of orders by meal period. Then I'm creating individual columns for each time period (trying to un-pivot my data).

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
SELECT year AS year
, week AS week
, case
    when type like('Q%') then 'Q'
    when type like('T%') then 'T'
    else 'Other'
    end 
    AS style
, restaurant_id AS rest_id
, case WHEN style = 'T' then (
        case
            when cast(order_time as time format 'HH:MI:SS') between '03:00:01' and '11:30:00' then 'Breakfast'
            when cast(order_time as time format 'HH:MI:SS') between '11:30:01' and '16:30:00' then 'Lunch'
            else 'Dinner'
            end
        )
        else (
        case
    when cast(order_time as time format 'HH:MI:SS') between '03:00:01' and '10:00:00' then 'Breakfast'
    when cast(order_time as time format 'HH:MI:SS') between '10:00:01' and '14:59:00' then 'Lunch'
    else 'Dinner'
    end)
    end
    as meal_period
, count(distinct case when meal_period = 'Breakfast' then order_number else null end) as food_count_b
, count(distinct case when meal_period = 'Lunch' then order_number else null end) as food_count_l
, count(distinct case when meal_period = 'Dinner' then order_number else null end) as food_count_d
FROM table1
group by 1,2,3,4,5
order by 1,2,3,4,5
```

And it produces a table like this:

```
year  week  style rest_id  meal_period  food_count_b  food_count_l  food_count_d
2017  1     T     1234     Breakfast    5
2017  1     T     1234     Lunch                      18
2017  1     T     1234     Dinner                                    17
2017  1     Q     9955     Breakfast    8
2017  1     Q     9955     Lunch                      21
2017  1     Q     9955     Dinner                                    24
2017  2     T     1234     Breakfast    4
2017  2     T     1234     Lunch                      20
2017  2     T     1234     Dinner                                    18
2017  2     Q     9955     Breakfast    6
2017  2     Q     9955     Lunch                      29
2017  2     Q     9955     Dinner                                    31
```

What I'd really like is to not have the meal_period column, I only created it to make it easier to divide the counts by meal period for their own columns (food_count_b, food_count_l, and food_count_d).

Ideally I'd like my table like this:

```
year  week  style rest_id  food_count_b  food_count_l  food_count_d
2017  1     T     1234     5             18            17
2017  1     Q     9955     8             21            24
2017  2     T     1234     4             20            18
2017  2     Q     9955     6             29            31
```

Any idea on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options..

1.) Take out `meal_period` entirely, then use the logic from that column directly in the other columns you wish to keep.

For example, change this:

```
count(distinct case when meal_period = 'Breakfast' then order_number else null end) as food_count_b
```

To something like this (I don't quite get your logic but you should get the idea):

```
count(distinct case when style = 'T' and cast(order_time as time format 'HH:MI:SS') between '03:00:01' and '11:30:00' 
                    then order_number
                    when style <> 'T' and cast(order_time as time format 'HH:MI:SS') between '03:00:01' and '10:00:00'
                    then order_number
                    else null end) as food_count_b
```

2.) Make your entire query a derived table then change the outer select:

```
SELECT year, week, style, rest_id, MAX(Food_Count_b), MAX(Food_Count_l), MAX(Food_Count_d)
FROM (
SELECT year AS year
, week AS week
, case
    when type like('Q%') then 'Q'
    when type like('T%') then 'T'
    else 'Other'
    end 
    AS style
, restaurant_id AS rest_id
, case WHEN style = 'T' then (
        case
            when cast(order_time as time format 'HH:MI:SS') between '03:00:01' and '11:30:00' then 'Breakfast'
            when cast(order_time as time format 'HH:MI:SS') between '11:30:01' and '16:30:00' then 'Lunch'
            else 'Dinner'
            end
        )
        else (
        case
    when cast(order_time as time format 'HH:MI:SS') between '03:00:01' and '10:00:00' then 'Breakfast'
    when cast(order_time as time format 'HH:MI:SS') between '10:00:01' and '14:59:00' then 'Lunch'
    else 'Dinner'
    end)
    end
    as meal_period
, count(distinct case when meal_period = 'Breakfast' then order_number else null end) as food_count_b
, count(distinct case when meal_period = 'Lunch' then order_number else null end) as food_count_l
, count(distinct case when meal_period = 'Dinner' then order_number else null end) as food_count_d
FROM table1
group by 1,2,3,4,5
) a
GROUP BY year, week, style, rest_id
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I used the second option!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TMP_TABLE TABLE
(
    idx INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Column1 NVARCHAR(50),
    Column2 NVARCHAR(50),
    Column3 NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @TMP_TABLE (
                           Column1,
                           Column2,
                           Column3
                       )
VALUES (   N'Value1', -- Column1 - nvarchar(50)
           N'Value2', -- Column2 - nvarchar(50)
           N'Value 3'   -- Column3 - nvarchar(50)
       )

SELECT  [idx] = T.idx,
        [Column1] = T.Column1,
        [Column2] = T.Column2,
        [Column3] = T.Column3
FROM @TMP_TABLE T
```

Comment: or insert everything in a table variable and group by then

Comment: How do I insert everything in a table variable? In Teradata you have to select all columns when there's an aggregation, so I can't use your replace group by approach.